# C++ Function to be called later

Tags: c++, function

I am a complete beginner just started to learning C++. I want to make function say a formula which would take square of a variable. Check the code below to understand better

```
 double raiseToPow(double x, int power)
{
    double result;
    int i;
    result = 1.0;

    for (i = 1; i <= power; i++)
    {
        result *= x;
    }

    return (result);
}
```

The above code would be used to square a variable.
I know you can save functions and then recall them to be used in the program. But I do not know how? Do I save it in a separate file and then recall it or do I write above every code. I do have searched Stackoverflow with the same query but most of the questions are way too advance for me to understand them and replicate them. Is there simple and beginner friendly explanation. Or some video that would be great.

Best Regards

Comment: There's no such thing as "save functions and then recall them to be used in the program" in C++. That just -- doesn't mean anything in C++'s terms. There's only one thing that can be done with functions: call them. Which C++ textbook are you using to learn C++, and what is the topic of the chapter where this practice problem is from? It's remotely possible that this is refererring to function pointers. But you would've mentioned something along those lines, were this to be the case.

Comment: then I must have completely misunderstood what our professor was trying to say. Thanks for correction and explanation though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, add a `main` function and call that function. Add this to your code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double value = 2.0;
    double result = raiseToPow(value, 2);
    std::cout << result << 'n';
    return 0;
}
```

Compile the file into an executable and run the executable.